# How can I display "username" instead of "domain\username" in PHP form?

Tags: php, windows

I have been searching this for days. Actually surprised that there is no answer. I have a PHP form that I want to display just the IIS logged in user without the domain prefix. It has been driving me nuts! Thanks for looking.

This is what i have now:

```
    $user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
        echo "$user"; ?>" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="uneditablefield"/>
```

Comment: `echo end(explode('\\', $user));`?

Comment: `echo strstr($user, '\\')`?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. (I have only been writing PHP for a few days...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing domain\ with str_ireplace()? Assuming that the domain is constant, otherwise Jon's comment would be the better choice.

Comment: Problem is that I am going between PAT and PROD environments with different domain names, (and character length). Jon's worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just chop off the prefix?

```
$user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
$user = array_pop (explode ("\\", $user));
    echo "$user"; ?>" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="uneditablefield"/>
```